# SwiftMailer - php attach txt file in mail

Tags: php, twig, email-attachments, swiftmailer

I am trying to put a part with text attachment into mail in my Symfony project. 
None of examples I tried works.

On dump(), everything is returning what it should.

Where is the catch?

```
 $projectDir = $this->container->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();
 $file = $projectDir . '/web/uploads';

    // Send email
    $message = $this->container->get('mail')->createTemplatedEmail(
        $user->getEmail(),
    ('Your Text File has arrived!'),
        '@WebsiteTemplates/member/view.html.twig',
        [
            'user' => $user,
        ]
    );

    $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file . '/my-text-file.txt'));
    $this->container->get('mail')->sendMessage($message, true);

    return;
```

I know I need to pass it as array for my twig file to work like:

```
Hello {{ user.email }}!
Here is your Text file: {{ txtFile }}<br>
```

It returns a file in a email like:

> Content-Type: text/x-vcard; name=dmchenry-svb-com.vcf Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dmchenry-svb-com.vcf QkVHSU46VkNBUkQNClZFUlNJT046My4wDQpSRVY6MjAxOS0wMy0xMVQxNToxODozOVoNCk47Q0hB

Comment: Did u verify that `$file . '/my-text-file.txt'` actually exists?

Comment: Yes. It's right there. I have trouble passing that attach file trough array like $user in exmaple.. @DarkBee

Comment: If `$message` is an instance of `Swift_Message` and `$file` exists, then the code u've posted should work as is

Comment: I updated question! Please respond. @DarkBee